# Rsync error using replicate command with cobbler

Tags: centos, rsync, cobbler

I am having an issue with creating a cobbler clone using the `replicate` command. I have a total of 4 distros in the original cobbler. All of them are being cloned correctly, except for one. This is the error I get when I am running replicate:

```
received on stderr: 
Rsyncing distro FC22-ws-i386
running: rsync -avzH cobbler_machine::distro-FC22-ws-i386 /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/fedora22_ws
received on stdout: 
received on stderr: @ERROR: Unknown module 'distro-FC22-ws-i386'
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

I tried finding similar examples of the @ERROR: Unkown module, but I couldn't use the other cases I found online to get a solution for my issue. Rsync works properly for all the other ones. I am suspecting there is something missing inside of the fedora22_ws directory, but I don't know what it could be. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a valid `[distro-FC22-ws-i386]` section in your `rsyncd.conf` on `cobbler_machine`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephen Harris in my comments I got pointed to the right direction. `cobbler sync` is supposed to generate the content inside of /etc/rsyncd.conf if /etc/cobbler/settings `manage_rsync` is enabled. In my case it was enabled but for some reason rsyncd.conf did not get populated with some of the distros. Running a `cobbler sync` on the master populated rsyncd.conf and solved the issue.